# Is anyone having trouble Ctrl-R, T running a specific locally highlighted test when it is set to async?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mstest

I noticed today that Ctrl-R, Ctrl-T on the highlighted test method in the GUI does not debug the test I just wrote when it looks like:

```
 [TestMethod]
 public async void Test()
    {
          await asyncMethod();
    }
```

The project builds, but the test doesn't run. There is no fail message or error message to be found anyplace.

If I simply remove the async keyword, then everything works fine. What's up with this?

In the code, I'm awaiting my asynchronous call. I don't see why the test runner couldn't deal with it.

EDIT:

After looking at the tests output, the message was this:

UTA007: Method blah defined in class blah  does not have correct signature. Test method marked with the [TestMethod] attribute must be non-static, public, return-type as void  and should not take any parameter. Example: public void Test.Class1.Test(). Additionally, return-type must be Task if you are running async unit tests. Example: public async Task Test.Class1.Test2()
========== Discover test finished: 3 found (0:00:00.1367583) ==========

I usually don't look at it, visual studio wants to show me the build output and the errors more often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test discovery process will not permit `async void` unit tests; I believe it will place a warning in the Output window. Since the `async void` method is skipped over by the test discovery, it won't actually run.

For asynchronous unit tests, use `async Task` instead of `async void`. I have more details in [my recent MSDN article on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx).

Comment: I checked again and saw no warning in the output window. It's a pretty silent failure unless I'm blind as a bat

Comment: @IsaacBolinger: In the dropdown, choose to show output from `Tests`. I get this: `UTA007: Method TestMethod1 defined in class UnitTestProject1.UnitTest1 does not have correct signature... return-type must be Task if you are running async unit tests. Example: public async Task Test.Class1.Test2()`

Comment: @Thomas: Since your problem is different, please create a minimal, reproducible example and post a question.